# use stormpath group as spring boot object

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, pojo, stormpath

Can you use your Stormpath group object(i.e. ADMIN) as a class in your Spring Boot application? I mean, I want to keep some state of this object and I do not want to keep a correspondent POJO, which would have the ADMIN's email and password, plus another data like a gender/birthday, but simply have the whole state and behaviour in a instance of the stormpath group ADMIN.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2):

When you say use your Stormpath group object 'as a class', I assume you mean 'as a Spring bean'?  If so, then most definitely!

For example:

```
import com.stormpath.sdk.client.Client;
import com.stormpath.sdk.group.Group;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

// ...

@Autowired
private Client client;

//I just made this property up - use any property name you want and
//define it in your Spring config and ensure the value is the 
//fully qualified Stormpath href corresponding to your admin group:
@Value("${groups.admin.href}")
private String adminGroupHref;

@Bean
public Group adminGroup() {
    return client.getResource(adminGroupHref, Group.class);
}
```

Then, elsewhere in your Spring config you can use `adminGroup()` to reference the group (in the save Java configuration class file).  Or, if you want to reference the Group as a bean in other Java configuration classes or @Component beans, just autowire it:

```
@Autowired
private Group adminGroup;
```

However, if you define more than one `Group` bean in your Spring Java config (maybe other groups? like `users` or `employees`?), then you'll need a `@Qualifier` when autowiring to ensure that the correct `Group` instance is injected:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("adminGroup")
private Group adminGroup;
```

All Stormpath resource instances (`Account`, `Group`, `Application`, etc) are thread-safe, making them safe to be used as singletons if desired.